# why are nuclear fallout shelters really necessary when radiation fades with distance so quickly?

Tags: radiation, nuclear-engineering

why are nuclear fallout shelters really necessary when radiation fades with distance so quickly?

it diminishes with the inverse square law. I1xD1^2 = I2xD2^2. (Standard procedure is to measure radiation at 1/4" from the source, or 0.0208333 feet) using that, you can have 1000 rads/hr on the roof of your residential house (about the most you will encounter), and sitting in your upper floor bedroom 15 feet beneath the roof, you only get 1.9 millirads/hr. Obviously on the first floor or basement you get even less.

why is there so much emphasis on getting to a nuclear fallout shelter, which is a big multi-story building with lots of mass between the roof and the occupants, such as a parking garage or library, when all that is really needed is maybe 20 feet of empty space? or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fallout  https://www.epa.gov/radtown/radioactive-fallout-nuclear-weapons-testing

Comment: I have seen a mushroom cloud. Not a nuclear explosion. It was an experiment by a logging company, burning off underbrush using IDK what—maybe napalm. It was about 90 miles from my home. Next morning, the cars in the driveway were covered with a film of ash. Probably so was everything else, but it was especially visible on the paint and windows of the cars. If it had been radioactive,  then I doubt I would have been here to tell the tale today.

Comment: or, IDK, maybe half that distance. It was 1972 or 1973. I was 11 ot 12 years old. Long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the fact that a nuclear blast will spread radioactive matter in an unimaginably giant dust cloud. In other words, every crack, every inch of every building, and even the dirt around your house will be completely suffused with radioactive particles. If you do not take shelter somewhere specifically designed to keep the radiation away from you, this radiation will almost certainly cause you massive amounts of trouble. It does not matter if you are far from the source when the radioactive material is right on top of you.

Comment: right, like... a parking garage? try again

Comment: A parking garage is an open structure. Unless you’re in the lower levels of a deep structure, you’re still going to be absolutely sand blasted by radioactive fallout.

Answer (score 0):

You are partly right. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallout_shelter) says

> ... an expedient purpose-built fallout shelter is a trench; with a strong roof buried by 1 m (3 ft) of earth. The two ends of the trench have ramps or entrances at right angles to the trench, so that gamma rays cannot enter (they can travel only in straight lines). To make the overburden waterproof (in case of rain), a plastic sheet may be buried a few inches below the surface and held down with rocks or bricks ...

It also says

> Unfiltered air is safe, since the most dangerous fallout has the consistency of sand or finely ground pumice.

A fallout shelter needs to survive the initial blast intact - which an above-ground structure may not. After that, the main danger in a fallout shelter is contaminating the shelter by bringing in fallout particles from the outside on shoes or clothing. Civil defence guidelines typically recommend isolating in the fallout shelter for at least two weeks. Of course, this requires pre-stocking the fallout shelter with uncontaminated water and food for at least two weeks, and dealing with other practical issues such as temperature regulation and sanitation.